# Rabbit MQ python script. Socket closed when connection was open

Tags: python, sockets, rabbitmq, pika

Need some help! While running the python script using Rabbit MQ RPC. I am getting a `Socket 104`,`Socket closed when connection was open` error. Below is python traceback and some code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server.py", line 34, in <module>
    channel.start_consuming()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1681, in start_consuming
    self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 656, in process_data_events
    self._dispatch_channel_events()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 469, in _dispatch_channel_events
    impl_channel._get_cookie()._dispatch_events()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1310, in _dispatch_events
    evt.body)
  File "./server.py", line 30, in on_request
    body=json.dumps(DEVICE_INFO))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1978, in basic_publish
    mandatory, immediate)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2065, in publish
    self._flush_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1174, in _flush_output
    *waiters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 395, in _flush_output
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies as i am unable to comment due to low reputation. Could you  provide a little more information on how you are opening your connection. Is it really open?

It might be because of loss of connection with rabbitmq server as pika doesn't deal with disconnects and often results in similar stacktrace.

I also had similar problem, in my case it was because my pika connection was dropping after sometime and my colleague was able to deal with this by adding a wait time for `mq:port_number`.

We were using docker container so we added following line to our invoke.sh to wait for mq:

`filename.py --wait-secs 30 --port-wait mq:5672`

I hope you are able to resolve this after doing that.

Otherwise it would be better to check if the connection is being dropped by pika before your python script runs or providing more information on how you are invoking it.

Comment: Can you help me on how to setting the wait time? I am running my scripts on my unix machine

Comment: Are you using [rabbitmqctl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html)? If so, it should have infinite timeout, or you can explicitly declare a timeout? I am not sure but you can check using nmap on port first if it is open or not. If it is open then, the issue would be something else. But if it is closed when you are getting this error then you can check on how to keep your rabbit mq server open. You can also forcibly open the port using netcat and then wait for rabbit mq to accept requests.

Comment: You could also checkout [rabbitmq.config](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) and increase handshake_timeout environment variable. But it would be better if you include more details in your post as that would help others understand your issue.